# JOIN Subselect range in ON Condition? (Why and behavioral benefits?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The statement in question is working correctly, I just need to understand why and how!

I have encountered the following Syntax in a statement which gets information for employee analysis.

Never seen anything like it and cannot find anything about the behavior using google. Hope you people can help me understand how this works and how to use it.

**Table 1 Employees  (EmployeeID, Name, Birthdate, ...)**

**Table 2 Contracts (ContractID, EmployeeID, Startdate, Enddate, ...)**

**Table 3 Time-models (TimeID, ContractID, EmployeeID, MonthlyDate, ...)**

**Table 4 Insurance (InsuranceID, ContractID, EmployeeID, JobType, ...)**

The subselect in the code later on outputs:

```
Columname MonthlyDate 
Values('2016-02-01 00:00:00.000',
'2016-04-01 00:00:00.000',
'2016-01-01 00:00:00.000',
'2016-03-01 00:00:00.000',
'2016-06-01 00:00:00.000',
'2016-05-01 00:00:00.000',
'2016-07-01 00:00:00.000')
```

The SQL in question looks like this:

```
SELECT E.EmployeeID+C.ContractID, D.Date, E.Name

FROM Employees AS E

LEFT OUTER JOIN Contract AS C ON E.EmployeeID = C.Employee ID

--This is where the SQL I was talking about starts
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT MonthlyDate
    FROM Time-models
    WHERE MonthlyDate >= Convert(DATETIME, '2016-01-01', 102)) AS D 
ON (D.MonthlyDate >= C.ContractStartDate AND D.MonthlyDate <= C.ContractEndDate) 
/*I can not explain this On-Condition*/

LEFT OUTER JOIN Insurance as I 
ON (I.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID AND I.ContractID = C.ContractID)

WHERE I.JobType = 'Clerk' 
AND (I.InsuranceStartDate <= D.MonthlyDate AND I.InsuranceEndDate >= D.MonthlyDate)
/* I can not understand which compare values are used in D.MonthlyDate 
because of the the vague ON-Condition */
```

Comment: When `LEFT JOIN`, put the right side table conditions in the `ON` clause to get true left join behavior! (When in WHERE, you get regular inner join result.) I.e. switch last WHERE to AND in your query!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do understand that. The thing is in the second join there is no equality to assign IDs as it is usually done, instead there is a range.

Comment: What is vague about the `ON` condition for the subquery?  For the purposes here, don't think of the subquery as anything other than another table.  The `ON` conditions work in exactly the same way as your other `JOIN`s.

Comment: @Blufftl  Ranges work the same way as equalities.  The rows are matched when the condition is met.  You don't always have to explicitly match on an ID value.

Comment: It is vague because there is no = instead there is a defined range.

Comment: What is the significance of the first of each month and it being within the employee's contract period? That's all this sub query or _derived table_ is actually defining. By defining that range in a join, you don't have to use sub queries in your WHERE clause which then uses that date range to check if the employee was insured. I'm making assumptions about your query's purpose.

Comment: @iamdave I understand it to the point of the subquery being another table. I don't understand how one single value can be matched.

Comment: @JonathonOgden your assumptions seem correct. so `I.InsuranceStartDate = D.MonthlyDate` is true if InsuranceStartDate is in the derived Table's range because there is a defined range in the `ON` condition?

Comment: @Blufft No, that statement would only be true if they were an *exact* match. `=` is an exact match; it doesn't compare ranges. Your `WHERE` clause is what checks if the employee's insurance is in the derived table's range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` condition of your query is turning the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.  (If a row doesn't match then the `I` columns will be `NULL` and fail the `WHERE` conditions.)

In addition:

- You do not need the subquery at all.
- SQL Server recognizes dates in the format YYYYMMDD and almost always in the format YYYY-MM-DD without conversion.

So, you might as well re-write the query as:

```
SELECT E.EmployeeID+C.ContractID, D.Date, E.Name
FROM Employees E JOIN
     Contract C
     ON E.EmployeeID = C.Employee ID JOI
     [Time-models] d
     ON D.MonthlyDate >= C.ContractStartDate AND
        D.MonthlyDate <= C.ContractEndDate AND
        MonthlyDate >= '2016-01-01' JOIN
     Insurance as I 
     ON I.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID AND
        I.ContractID = C.ContractID
WHERE I.JobType = 'Clerk' AND
      I.InsuranceStartDate <= D.MonthlyDate AND
      I.InsuranceEndDate >= D.MonthlyDate;
```

I'm not sure if this answers your question, though.

Comment: This was a great answer and actually helped understand everything even better! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

"I don't understand how one single value can be matched." 
No this apparently will match a number of rows, not a single one. Consider this simple example

```
select * 
from (
    values 
     (1, cast('2016-02-02' as date), cast('2016-03-02' as date))
    ,(2, cast('2016-02-02' as date), cast('2016-05-02' as date))
    ,(3, cast('2016-02-02' as date), cast('2016-02-04' as date))
    ) C(id,ContractStartDate, ContractEndDate)
left join ( 
    values
     ('2016-02-01')
    ,('2016-04-01')
    ,('2016-01-01')
    ,('2016-03-01')
    ,('2016-06-01')
    ,('2016-05-01')
    ,('2016-07-01')
    ) D(MonthlyDate) 
    on D.MonthlyDate >= C.ContractStartDate AND D.MonthlyDate <= C.ContractEndDate
;
```

The query will return 1 to 3 rows from `D` for every `C` row.

Comment: Thank you this helps me a lot!